# Perl-printing a 2-d matrix from a file

Tags: perl, matrix, subroutine, file-read

So i am trying to read a 2-d matrix in from a file so that I can multiply two matrices together. I can get the individual rows of the matrix to print, but I can't get the subroutine to return the entire matrix. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I pasted the test matrix from the file I am using:

```
 12345                                                                              
 67890                                                                  
 34567
```

The output I get is:

```
 final matrix is: ##THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO PRINT OUT BUT I GET NOTHING
 row is:12345
 row is:67890
 row is:34567
```

Comment: Pictures of code are not useful. Copy and paste code and input/output.

Comment: One of the problems is using a new variable declaration to store your values in. `my $matrix_name`, a scalar variable. It will be out of scope outside the else block. Also, it is not the same variable as `my @matrix_name`, which is an array with the same name. Furthermore, the statement `print my @var` is always going to print nothing, because you are declaring the variable, meaning it will be empty. You will not get a warning because it is an array. I cannot tell if there are more errors in your code because I cannot testrun an image and see if it works. :)

Comment: @Sarah please include an example of the input matrix file.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have posted the example of the input matrix file and pasted the input/output

Comment: @Sarah In the input file is there space between the numbers? For example in the first row you show as `12345`, but I suspect you meant to write it as `1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: If you want `$matrix` to have data in it then it feels like your `matrix_read_file` needs to return something.

Comment: @HåkonHægland it does not matter how I write it in the input file, I get the same result. I tried with and without spaces

Comment: @Sarah Why do you check if a line starts with letters: `if ($line =~ /^([A-Za-z]\w*)/)` ? Please clarify what this check is supposed to do

Comment: @HåkonHægland I thought just in case an input file has text in it I would remove the text and only keep the numbers for the matrix. If the input file only has numbers then I think I would no longer need this.

Comment: The last edit deleted all the code, was that deliberate? The question no longer has enough details to be answerable as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

{
    print "Enter filename: "; 
    chomp(my $matrix_file = <STDIN>);
    say "final matrix is:";
    my $matrix = matrix_read_file($matrix_file);
    print Dumper($matrix);
}

sub matrix_read_file {
    my ($filename) = @_;

    my @matrix;
    open (my $F, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open $filename: $!";
    while (my $line =<$F> ) {
        chomp $line;
        next if $line =~ /^\s*$/; # skip blank lines
        my @row = split /\s+/, $line;
        push @matrix, \@row;
    }
    close $F;
    return \@matrix;
}
```

If you give the following input file:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

The program outputs:

```
final matrix is:
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5'
          ],
          [
            '6',
            '7',
            '8',
            '9',
            '10'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: It worked! I'll compare it with mine and see what I did wrong thank you! I'm new to perl so if I run 2 files with matrices and want to pass these arrays to a new subroutine to multiply them together, would I refer to the matrix as \@VAR1? or just $VAR1?

Comment: Great! `$VAR1` is just something `Data::Dumper` prints. It is not related to the variable in the program. The variable is still named `$matrix` in the program.